# How to convert date "2018-12-13T07:33:35.893Z" to 13/12/2018

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried following way but doesn't work

```
dateTime="2018-12-13T07:33:35.893Z"

DateTime dt;

DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, out dt);
```

But I am always getting dt as `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`.

Can you please tell me why? and how can I convert that string to date?

I also tried `Convert.ToDateTime` but  doesn't work.

What I actually want is getting the `dd/MM/yyyy` string'd DateTime so I could perform a query on a DB.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That code wouldn't compile - `TryParseExact` has no overload accepting only a single string. Please post the actual code you're using. Basically, you need to tell `TryParseExact` the format of your string - that's the part you haven't shown us that part. Additionally, you should use the return value of `TryParseExact` to detect when parsing has failed.

Comment: As an aside: remember that a `DateTime` object doesn't have a format (it's just stored as a single number). If you need formatting, you need a string.

Comment: can you suggest for india

Comment: @Mangesh What do you mean "suggest for India"?

Comment: @MangeshUkade That's an ISO8601 date. It's the only format *not* affected by locales and timezones - `Z` specifies UTC. A simple `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTimeOffset.Parse()` just work. There's no reason to use `ParseExact`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MangeshUkade besides, `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` objects have no format. They are binary objects. If you want to display them in a certain way, specify the format string you want when converting them to strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateTime = "2018-12-13T07:33:35.893Z";
var x = DateTime.Parse(dateTime).ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy");
```

Comment: gives me an error string not reconized as valid DateTime

Comment: @MangeshUkade This date string is from *your* question.

Comment: yeah same date string but getting error

Comment: @MangeshUkade This code *does* work for me...

Comment: but not working for me  why

Comment: @MangeshUkade Did you paste my code *as-is* - without modifying?

Comment: @JohnyL what's the point of this code? The OP is trying to parse a date, not format a string. Unless the OP mistakenly assumes dates have formats and tries to parse the US date literal produced by `ToString()`. In any case, the OP asked for `dd/MM`, not `MM/dd`

Comment: yes its work fine finally

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the original `DateTime` object or you simply have it in a `string`?

In case you've got it as DateTime:

```
string european = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

In case you've got it as a string:

```
string date = "2018-12-13T07:33:35.893Z";

if(DateTime.TryParse(date , out DateTime result))
    result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Have a look at the original MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) about the `DateTime.ToString` method

Since you've got a DateTime you can convert to that format:

```
var thisExactMoment = DateTime.Now;
thisExactMoment.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

With your "dateTime" variable, just perform `dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` and you're ready to go.

Comment: gives an error for socond answer if(DateTime.TryParse(date , out DateTime result))
    result.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: System.DateTime is type but used as variabe

Comment: @MangeshUkade What do you actually need to get? A string with that dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: i want to pass that string to the database  for filtering data from DB

Comment: @MangeshUkade I've updated my solution with an example of using "now". It gets the system's time and converts it to `dd/MM/yyyy` string. It's applying the same to your `DateTime`.

Comment: DateTime.now is working fine for me but I want "2018-12-13T07:33:35.893Z"  this string conversion to DateTime  because this format i got from angular file for filteration purpose from date to TO date

Comment: @MangeshUkade My second case is your way to go. It performs a `TryParse` from that string so if it passes you get the string in the format you desired. In case you want to do whatever with the `DateTime` object itself, then use the `result` variable inside the `if` body.